# Wordpress NextGen Slider in Post

Tags: image, wordpress, plugins, slider, nextgen-gallery

I am configuring an image slider for a wordpress page's individual blog posts. Wanted to do this quickly so looked at incorporating the NextGen slider, but it seems like it is more geared towards putting images on wordpress 'pages' rather than wordpress 'posts'.

I want to create individual posts, each with a different NextGen slider. Whats the best way to organize this using the wordpress framework?

Currently, my slider lives at 'mysite.com/slider'. Can I set up NextGen so that different galleries point to 'mysite.com/post1', 'mysite.com/post2', etc.? If not, is there another way that you have found to perform this task?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Srijans answer, but the correct syntax is [nggallery id=x] , where 'x' equals the id of your gallery. Insert this shortcode the body of your post and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following shortcode in the body of your post.

```
[slideshow id,width,height]
```

Where the variable names have the intuitive meaning. You have to go to the plugin settings to retrieve the slideshow ids. This also means you can have different slideshows for different posts.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Srijan. are the width and height fields required? if i use thickbox, for example, it seems like the width and height are predetermined